# Avoid latex rotating pages orientation

Tags: floats, rotating

I am writing a document with the memoir class. What happens, for no apparent reason, is that latex starts rotating pages containing single figure at a certain point. 
I basically end up with a document where those pages, and only those, are rotated by 90°.

Snippet of code for the figure, to show that I didn't ask for this:

```
\documentclass[]{memoir} 

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{cite, epigraph}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{./path/cfig.eps}
 \caption{mycaption}\label{fig:langs15}
 \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The eps file I'm using is available at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32068837/cfig.eps

My document is large, and it started having this problem when I added this figure, but I don't think it has anything wrong.

Comment: I think this may be a problem with the `eps` file. Can you make it available for download and add a link to your question?

Comment: Your code should begin with `\documentclass{memoir}` and end with `\end{document}` so that we can copy/paste and compile it. Maybee something in the preamble is the cause of that behavior? + @IanThompson is right, to have the `eps` file could help us.

Comment: @IanThompson Yes, I edited the question.

Comment: You forgot (at least) the `\usepackage{graphicx}`. When I add this package, I can compile your MWE and the figure is not rotated.

Comment: are you sure it is really rotated or is it a feature of your pdf viewer some will "auto rotate" the view based on heuristics that suggest it might be a good idea.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle added all the packages I'm using. And, I think it's rotated, given that it appears so in every pdf viewer.

Comment: does _the document you posted_ show the problem, and if so how did you process it, latex/dvips xetex or ...(I'm assuming not pdflatex as you are using eps)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using Latexila on Ubuntu 12.04, compiling as latex->DVI->PDF (Latexmk) and this is the document which shows the problem. This figure is located, alone because of current lack of text, on page 46 of a long document, no problems before it. Its page appears rotated.

Comment: The answer to the question linked by @GonzaloMedina fixed the problem on my machine.

Comment: @IanThompson On mine too, it was then a feature of the conversion from ps to pdf. Thank you all!

Comment: @martina thanks anyway I see it's the auto-rotate feature but popping up in the pdf conversion instead of the pdf viewer:-)